# npm run build error for html-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, cesiumjs

Hey so I am new to webpack and I am trying to use it for a project using the Cesium js api. I am following their tutorial online to the T but for some reason when I run the command "npm run build" I get the following error without it executing properly.

```
Peris-MacBook-Pro:App peri$ npm run build

> ngafid@1.0.0 build /Users/peri/Desktop/App
> webpack --config webpack.config.js

(node:23326) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
(node:23326) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.apply is deprecated. Call apply on the plugin directly instead
/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/compiler.js:81
        var outputName = compilation.mainTemplate.applyPluginsWaterfall('asset-path', outputOptions.filename, {
                                                  ^

TypeError: compilation.mainTemplate.applyPluginsWaterfall is not a function
    at /Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/compiler.js:81:51
    at compile (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:222:11)
    at hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:470:14)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:35:21)
    at compilation.seal.err (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:467:30)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:35:21)
    at hooks.optimizeAssets.callAsync.err (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:957:35)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:35:21)
    at hooks.optimizeChunkAssets.callAsync.err (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:948:32)
    at _err0 (eval at create (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at /Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:262:11
    at _class.runTasks (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/uglify/index.js:63:9)
    at UglifyJsPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:182:16)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:35:21)
    at hooks.additionalAssets.callAsync.err (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:943:36)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:35:21)
    at hooks.optimizeTree.callAsync.err (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:939:32)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:35:21)
    at Compilation.seal (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:881:27)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:464:17)
    at _err0 (eval at create (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at _addModuleChain (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:749:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/peri/Desktop/App/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:688:9)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ngafid@1.0.0 build: `webpack --config webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ngafid@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/peri/.npm/_logs/2018-02-27T04_17_33_336Z-debug.log
```

I have this in my wepack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');

const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
        }, {
            test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg|xml|json)$/,
            use: [ 'url-loader' ]
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

and I have added the following script line in my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.. I tried to see if the warnings were the issue but that doesn't seem to be it. I am assuming its that function that is causing the error, but how do I fix it? Many Thanks!

Comment: My first guess is that you're using incompatible versions of Webpack and the HtmlWebpackPlugin. What versions of those are you using? (Check your `package-lock.json` to be sure).

Comment: Just for completeness, please add your package.json file extract to the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those who are looking for an updated solution to this question, the module `webpack-contrib/html-webpack-plugin` does not exist anymore. For more details you may look up at the [discussion](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/841) here. The solution,`npm install html-webpack-plugin --save-dev` works. If this throws a run time error described in the OP's question, you can try installing a version specific module, `npm i html-webpack-plugin@4.4.0`. Hopefully this should work for you, as it did for me.

Comment: the `npm i html-webpack-plugin@4.4.0 --save-dev` saved me, thanks

Answer (score 10):

Webpack 4 has some deprecation changes and an author of the html-webpack-plugin hasn't changed the code for the new requirements and that's why this plugin doesn't work with the new webpack 4 version.

The core webpack team forked this plugin till the author change the initial code and theirs fork available by this package [contrib/html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-webpack-plugin)

So you should install this fork instead the original one.

You can do it by simply installing from npm or yarn
eg

```
npm i -D html-webpack-plugin@webpack-contrib/html-webpack-plugin
```

or with yarn

```
yarn add -D html-webpack-plugin@webpack-contrib/html-webpack-plugin
```

There are no requirement to use exactly yarn =)  you can do it via npm as well

More detailed info: [Webpack 4 release announce](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-released-today-6cdb994702d4)

Comment: The webpack team writes on [the release notes for v4](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-released-today-6cdb994702d4): *UPDATE (3/1/2018): html-webpack-plugin@3 is now available with v4 support!!!!*  This means now it should suffice to run  `npm i --save-dev html-webpack-plugin`

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this issue by installing the beta version of [HTML Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin).

```
npm i --save-dev html-webpack-plugin@next
```

Answer (score -4):

first:

`npm install -g yarn`

Then:

`yarn add webpack-contrib/html-webpack-plugin -D`